# How to handle file upload on client using react hook form and next.js 14 server actions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, serialization, server-side-rendering

I have a file input registered with react Hook form with next.js 14

```
"use client"
..........more code  
  <form action={handleSubmit(updateUserProfile)}>
        <input
                    {...register("avatar_url")}
                    type="file"
                    name="avatar_url"
                    accept="image/*"                
                  />
        <button type="submit">upload</button>
    </from>
......rest of the code goes here
```

and below is my async function

```
 async function updateUserProfile(formData) {
    // updateCurrentUserProfile is server action with supabase storage api, w/ server client
    const response = await updateCurrentUserProfile(formData);
  }
```

If I don't select any file this works smoothly without any error. but if I select a file to upload. i get error

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

```
Uncaught Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Server Actions. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.
```

I don't want to create any route handler. I want to upload the images using server actions only. I tried to construct a new FormData but that was not passing the file to the server actions instead it's just sending an empty array of FileList objects.

Comment: yes. just pass the FormData with form action, this won't work with rhf.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue trying to upload images with RHF and server actions.

My workaround is:

```
 const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormTypes> = async data => {
 // ? workaround to upload the images with server action and RHF
 const formData = new FormData()
 data.documents.forEach((document) => {
   formData.append('documents', document)
 })

 const formData: FormTypes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
 const request = await serverActionFunction(data, formData)
 console.log(request)
}
```

server action:

```
const serverActionFunction = (data: FormTypes, formData: FormData) => {
 return {data, formData}
}
```